# How to debug the Visual Studio Code Python extension formatting capability?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have followed the steps on the Visual Studio Code Python extension concerning formatting
(I have enabled `editor.formatOnSave`, set a path for the black formatter, switched to `black` as formatter for the python extension, even made sure that black was in the path for the terminal -- unrelated).
But still, there's no message in the Python extension output, and the code keeps being unformatted.

I am on macOS, the selected python interpreter is a pipenv 2.7 interpreter (but black is available at a different location, set as `python.formatter.blackPath`)

Thus, how to debug the formatting capability of this extension?

Comment: Make sure you can take what you set for `python.formatter.blackPath` and run `<path to black> --diff <file to format>`.

Comment: And did you set `python.formatter.provider`?

Comment: @brett cannon, of course both are true. D'you know how to debug visual studio code extensions?

Comment: trust me, you can't assume anything is obvious when providing technical support, i.e. it's easy to forget to to a small thing.

Comment: For how to debug, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/developing-extensions

Comment: Thanks Brett, I will have a look at it during my holidays, and I'll propose a PR if I find a bug. Have a good day, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello Brett, I have debugged the extension, but I am still unable to find the reason for which it doesn't work. What I see: the `const edits = await formatter.formatDocument(document, options, token, range)` returns a non-empty list of edits, but the file is not updated with changes.
However, black is setup correctly (the edits list is non empty, and it actually corresponds to the changes I have made! :-)).

Comment: I would say that this is a question of how big the setTimeout second parameter is.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on the extension at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues to help debug this farther.